# Need button to be active if all objects are dropped on correct boxes - Drag and Drop game

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, attributes, boolean

I have made a Drag and drop game which has 4 objects to be dropped on 4 targets with correct order. I want an button or animation to activate after dropping all objects on correct boxes. Drag and Drop part is done but i want to check if all objects are dropped or not. Any existing examples will be helpful. I have medium level skills on java script

HTML

```
<div class="button" id="button" onclick="on();"><a href="next.html"><img src="image/next.png"></a></div>

    <div id="jumbledWordsWrapper" class="jumble">

    <span id="150" data-source-id="Increases Sperm Production" draggable="true" class="onefif">Increases Sperm Production</span>
    <span id="1" data-source-id="Augments sperm motility" draggable="true" class="one">Augments sperm motility</span>
   <span id="2" data-source-id="Enhances Sperm Protection" draggable="true" class="two">Enhances Sperm Protection</span>
   <span id="CarniQ" data-source-id="Improves sperm morphology" draggable="true" class="CarniQ">Improves sperm morphology</span></div>

  <div id="orderedWordsWrapper" class="order">

  <span data-target-id="Increases Sperm Production" class="oneff"></span>

  <span data-target-id="Augments sperm motility" class="ttwo"></span>

  <span data-target-id="Enhances Sperm Protection" class="oon"></span>

  <span data-target-id="Improves sperm morphology" class="cc"></span>

</div>
```

js

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   const jumbledWords = document.querySelectorAll('#jumbledWordsWrapper > span');
   const orderedWords = document.querySelectorAll('#orderedWordsWrapper > span');

  jumbledWords.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler);
  el.addEventListener('dragend', dragEndHandler);
})
  orderedWords.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnterHandler);
  el.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverHandler);
  el.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeaveHandler);
  el.addEventListener('drop', dropHandler);
})

  function dragStartHandler(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', e.target.getAttribute('data-source-id'));
  e.target.style = 'opacity: 0.3';
}
  function dragEndHandler(e) {
  e.target.style = 'opacity: 1';
}

  function dragEnterHandler(e) {
  e.target.style = 'border: 2px dashed gray; box-sizing: border-box; background: whitesmoke';
}

  function dragOverHandler(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

function dragLeaveHandler(e) {
  e.target.style = 'border:1px soild white; background: white';
}

function dropHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  dragLeaveHandler(e); 
  
  const dataSourceId = e.dataTransfer.getData('text'); 
  const dataTargetId = e.target.getAttribute('data-target-id');
  
  if(dataSourceId === dataTargetId) {
    e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', dataSourceId);
    e.target.style = 'border: none; background: #fff';
    
    let sourceElemDataId = 'span[data-source-id="' + dataSourceId + '"]';
    let sourceElemSpanTag = document.querySelector(sourceElemDataId);
    
    Object.assign(sourceElemSpanTag, {
      className: 'no-longer-draggable',
      draggable: false,
    });
  }
  
}
 function on() {
  let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".no-longer-draggable");
                console.log(nodeList);

    for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {
    // print the tag name of the node (DIV, SPAN, etc.)
    var curr_node = nodeList[i];
   // console.log(curr_node.tagName);

    for(var j = 0; j < curr_node.attributes.length; ++j) {
        var curr_attr = curr_node.attributes[j];
        console.log(curr_attr.name, curr_attr.value);

     if (curr_attr.name=='id' && curr_attr.value=='150' &&  curr_attr.value=='1' && curr_attr.value=='2' && 
      curr_attr.value=='CarniQ'  && curr_attr.value=='CCQ' ) 
      
      { }

   else
   {
    
   }
}
}
}



</script>
```

CSS

```
        
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


  html, body {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background:#417dbf;
    color:#fff;
  }

.no-longer-draggable {
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
  background: lightgray !important;
  opacity: 0.0 !important;
}

.background{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
.background img{width: 100%;}


h2 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.jumble{
    position: fixed;
    top: 18%;
    left: 11%;
    z-index: 5;
}

#jumbledWordsWrapper span {
    /*background: white;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    top: 81%;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: auto;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 13px 19px;
    margin: 0 0px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;  

}
#orderedWordsWrapper span {
    padding: 6px 9px;
    position: fixed;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 28px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.order{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 55%;
    z-index: 5;

}

.copy{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 25%;
    width: 47%;
    height: auto;
    top: 4%;
}

.copy img{width: 100%;}

.lock{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 7%;
    width: 38%;
    height: auto;
    top: 30%;
}

.lock img{width: 100%;}

.puzzle{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 5%;
    width: 46%;
    height: auto;
    top: 25%;
}

.puzzle img{width: 100%;}

.onefif{
    color: red;
    position: fixed;
    font-weight: bold;
    right: 424px;
    bottom: 117px;
}

.one{
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
    right: 373px;
    bottom: 117px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.two{
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
    right: 317px;
    bottom: 117px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.CarniQ{
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
    right: 20%;
    width: 8%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 14%;
}

.CarniQ img {width:100%;}

.ccq{
    position: fixed;
    right: 9%;
    width: 8%;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 14%;
}

.ccq img {width:100%;}

.oneff{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    width: 42px!important;
    left: 55%;
    z-index: 5;
}


.ttwo{
    position: fixed;
    top: 39%;
    width: 42px!important;
    left: 79%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.oon{
    position: fixed;
    top: 39%;
    width: 42px!important;
    left: 56%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.cc{
    position: fixed;
    top: 55%;
    left: 55%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.cqq{
    position: fixed;
    top: 55%;
    left: 70%;
    z-index: 5;
}

.white_box1{
    height: 71%;
    width: 81%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 6%;
    left: 9%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.white_box1 img{width:100%;}


.oat{
    height: auto;
    width: 11%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 6%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.oat img{width:100%;}


.ref{
    height: auto;
width: 79%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 6%;
    left: 3%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.ref img{width:100%;}

.border_t{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.border_t img{width:100%;}


.border_d{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.border_d img{width:100%;}

.button{
    height: auto;
    width: 11%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 4%;
    right: 4%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.button img{width:100%;}
```

I tried setting boolean on draggable objects to detect if they are dropped.

Comment: Can you post your CSS as well?

Comment: @FiddlingAway  I added css and code for button for next page, I want that button to be disabled initially and to be activated only when the drag and drop activity is done i.e. all 4 objects on 4 correct targets , so user can progress to next page. Thanks

Comment: Do  you mean something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/p5z3ngqv/)? You can check the code I added by searching for `start here`. The idea is to check how many draggable elements are there, after dropping one of them in the correct slot - if there are none, an `alert(...)` is triggered. I think you can build on that.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late reply, i was looking for something like this.